# Performance problem to access QgsLineString vertex

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am writing a QGIS processing plugin.  I need to have accessible to Python in a list of xy tuple [(x0,y0),(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...], the x,y coordinate of each vertex of each QgsLineString.  The fastest way I found yet was with the following code:

```
qgs_pnts = qgs_line_string.points() 
xy = [(qgs_pnt.x(), qgs_pnt.y()) for qgs_pnt in qgs_pnts]
```

Where qgs_line_string is a QgsLineString object.  I have to work with a lot of information. With the Python profiler I was able to estimate that the code above was taking 25% of the execution time just to load the QgsLineString into a list of xy tuple.  I understand why it's taking so much time the comprehension list is making two C calls for each vertex of the QgsLineString object.

My question: is there another way in pyqgs to load faster the vertex of a QgsLineString object  into a Python list of xy tuple?

Answer (score 2):

My first goal was to try to stay within python and pygqs and avoid numpy or other external libraries. I do not know if numpy is part of the standard QGIS distribution. I found an interesting faster function in pyqgs. So instead of:

```
qgs_pnts = qgs_line_string.points() 
xy = [(qgs_pnt.x(), qgs_pnt.y()) for qgs_pnt in qgs_pnts]
```

I use the one line:

```
xy = [(qgs_line_string.xAt(i), qgs_line_string.yAt(i)) for i in range(qgs_line_string.numPoints())]
```

Which is 4 time faster than the original code.  Less dynamic list construction and no need to create a list of QgsPoint. See below with execution on Jupyter notebook.

```
# Creation of a 10000 vertice line string
lst_pnts = []
lst_coord = []
for i in range (10000):
    lst_pnts.append(QgsPoint(i,i+1))
    lst_coord.append((i,i+1))
qgs_ls = QgsLineString(lst_pnts)

# Extraction through list QgsPoint
now = datetime.now()
for i in range(1000):
    qgs_pnts = qgs_ls.points()
    coords = [(p.x(),p.y()) for p in qgs_pnts]
now1 = datetime.now()
print ("List of QgsPoint: ", now1-now)

# Extraction without list of QgsPoint
now = datetime.now()
for i in range(1000):
    coords = [(qgs_ls.xAt(i), qgs_ls.yAt(i)) for i in range(qgs_ls.numPoints())]
now1 = datetime.now()
print ("No list of QgsPoint: ", now1-now)
```

**Python output:**

```
List of QgsPoint:  0:00:12.999123
No list of QgsPoint:  0:00:03.084472
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing many lists with 2 elements. Lists are not very fast.

Is it not easier to just call:
qgs_pnt.x()
as required? No list is created.

If you are converting to Numpy arrays (Nx2), then allocate the array first and read in x and y data to the preallocated array.

```
data = np.empty((N,2))
for i in range(N):
    data[i,0] = qgs_pnt.x()
    data[i,1] = qgs_pnt.y()
```

Relative performance will be better if each LineString has many points. If not, consider making a super-array in Numpy and viewing slices of it to get the specific LineString you seek.

Comment: You are right,  python lists are slow in but the operations that really slows the process here are qgs_pnt.x() and qgs_pnt.y() probably because of the C call. I'm looking here for a faster way to load QgsLineString into a python list.

Comment: It's a compound statement, I think, combining the C call to the Point with the creation in Python of a list. Did you specifically compare timing for x = p.x() with xy=[x,y]? In my experience, especially when using Cython, C calls are very fast, as they are statically typed and Python is built in C. Python lists, however, tend to be dynamically typed and may take much longer to create. That is why I suggested creating a larger Numpy array and filling it directly, avoiding lists altogether. Another option may be to try to vectorize the code using Numba.